# Is it possbile to load different vite server config via vite.config.js based on development setup

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm working on a Laravel 10 project together with a friend. We both use different detups in our development. I use Laravel from a homestead setup and my friend uses sail in combination with docker.

My vite.config.js with homestead looks as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: "192.168.56.56",
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
    },

});
```

My friends version with sail is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],

});
```

The latter also works with our deployment scripts for automated production build.

Is there any way I can have both configurations in the vite.config.js file without needing to change them every time?

Tried to exclude vite.config.js from git, but this causes also the automated production deployment to stop working, so it would be great to be able to have both configurations in there.

Comment: I am not sure where but check the file that references the `vite.config.js`. Then create 2 or more files of `vite.config.js` one for homestead, one for your friend, maybe one more for production build if needed, something like `homestead-vite.config.js` etc. Then add in your .env which `vite.config.js` you want to load and then use that .env variable to switch which vite you want to use.

Comment: When I say switch I mean switch it in the file that references the `vite.config.js`

Comment: I cant give you a direct answer but this should be a start

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll look into it and come back if this provides a solution.

Comment: You could also just use then .env value in your vite.config.js and then assign the value of `defineConfig` in an object (switchable with .env value).